# Simple HLOOKUP Failing with Excel 2010

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, worksheet-function, spreadsheetgear

I have an Excel spreadsheet (generated by spreadsheet gear, but it's more an Excel problem) that isn't functioning as i would expect when I use [HLOOKUPS](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/hlookup-HP005209114.aspx).  I use a simple HLOOKUP to look up the value at a given percent in a table.  For two certain values, the HLOOKUP fails.  These values are 0.9993 and 0.999.  This excel document demonstrates the problem:  http://dsokol.com/tokio/excelna.xlsx.  Cells C6 and C7 are showing as N/A, when they are intended to be populated with B and C.  If I re-key over the values, the HLOOKUPs start working again.

Can anyone explain why this is occurring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Barry. This problem is not related to whether or not they are numbers or strings(they are all numbers). This appears to be a limitation of storing floating point numbers in binary - as described here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214118

> Many combinations of arithmetic operations on floating-point numbers
>   in Microsoft Excel and Microsoft Works may produce results that appear
>   to be incorrect by very small amounts. For example, the equation 
>   =1*(.5-.4-.1)  may be evaluated to the quantity (-2.78E-17), or -0.0000000000000000278 instead of 0.

This problem is not unique to excel either but rather a result of:

> IEEE 754 specifies that numbers be stored in binary format to reduce
>   storage requirements and allow the built-in binary arithmetic
>   instructions that are available on all microprocessors to process the
>   data in a relatively rapid fashion. However, some numbers that are
>   simple, nonrepeating decimal numbers are converted into repeating
>   binary numbers that cannot be stored with perfect accuracy.

This phenomenon is visible here in "Arithmetic Equality":

[image: InterestingProblem]

Again this is not a problem that is unique to excel:

> This behavior is not a problem in or a limitation of Excel or Works;
>   this behavior occurs because the Institute of Electrical and
>   Electronics Engineers (IEEE) 754 floating-point standard requires that
>   numbers be stored in binary format.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is those numbers are being stored as strings and not  integers. I guess you need to explicitly declare the column type in SpreadSheet Gear.

If you open the xlsx file as a zip file, and extract `Sheet1.xml` from the `xl\WorkSheets` folder before and after overwriting the values, any diff tool (e.g. winmerge makes this obvious).

I have posted the XML differences on [this gist](https://gist.github.com/3821711).

Comment: I didn't know you could unzip excel files and view the internals.  I was messing around with a hex editor for nothing!

Comment: @DavidJ.Sokol this is true for any MSFT file that has a four letter extention that ends in X. The X stands for XML.

Comment: In the Excel sheet posted all the values are numbers, e.g. =ISNUMBER(C2) and ISNUMBER(C5) both give TRUE. I suspect the cause is related to this http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214118